# ls: cannot access /dev/ttyACM0: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have installed the Hokuyo UTM-30LX driver as followed by http://www.isep.ipp.pt/roswiki/hokuyo_node%282f%29Tutorials%282f%29UsingTheHokuyoNode.html.
And then I typed $ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 in the terminal, but it displayed that  ls: cannot access /dev/ttyACM0: No such file or directory.
Why? Any help is appreciated!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40934/ls:-cannot-access-/dev/ttyacm0:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no device. Is it plugged in and powered up properly?

The device might also be any like /dev/ttyACM*.

Are there any error messages when you type `dmesg`?
To check what is relevant, unplug the device, `dmesg`, replug it, `dmesg`, and see what changes. There should be either some messages reported the new device (also giving the device) or error messages.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3